# SQL - Distinct count between two tables

Tags: sql

I'm having a mind lapse on what I believe is a relatively easy script. Hopefully I'm overthinking the logic.

What I'm trying to do is perform two counts on a distinct column which is right joined.

What I want is:

```
    count(a.book_id) as count_of_books
    count(b.book_ref_number) as count_of_losses
```

Expected Output

```
--------------------------------------------------------
| Book          | count_of_books      | count of losses|
--------------------------------------------------------
|Hunger Games   | 76                  | 31             |
--------------------------------------------------------
|Hop on Pop     | 27                  | 6              |
--------------------------------------------------------
|Pout Pout Fish | 138                 | 43             |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

[image]

I have tried a couple different scripts. Here are the two scripts I've tried.

```
   (select count(*) from Inventory_Table x  ) Count1,
   (select count(*) from Loss_table b  ) Count2
   from Inventory_Table x
   right join Loss_table b on b.book_ref_number = x.book_id
   where rownum < 20



   select
   a.book_name,
   count(distinct a.book_id),
   count(b.book_ref_number)
   from Inventory_Table x
   right join Loss_table b  on trim(b.book_ref_number) = trim(a.book_id)
```

Results I get

```
--------------------------------------------------------
| Book          | count_of_books      | count of losses|
--------------------------------------------------------
|Moby Dick      | 4376                | 2574           |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm looking for guidance in my neglectful mistake. Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm lost.  Your query has nothing to do with the tables that you have shown.

Comment: My fault Gordon. Wrong SQL script for the 2nd

Answer (score 0):

`and rownum <20` doesn't make sense. you are limiting your result set with 20 records.

try this:

```
select * from (
select
   a.mrch_Nr,
   count(distinct a.fdr_trac_nr),
   count(b.auth_id)
from DATASTORE_FD.DEB_CRD_AUTH_LOG_REC a
right join jordab26.ft b on trim(b.auth_id) = trim(a.fdr_trac_nr)
where a.auth_log_dt between '20200101' and '20200408' 
group by a.mrch_nr
) 
where rownum < 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I'm not sure about `rownum < 20`. Also, make sure your add correct group by condition.

```
select sum(case book_id when null then 0 else 1 end )  count_of_books,
          sum(case book_ref_number when null then 0 else 1 end ) count_of_losses
     from Inventory_Table x
   right join Loss_table b on b.book_ref_number = x.book_id
   where rownum < 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
      Select distinct bookname, 
        count(distinct 
              a.bookid)+sum(
           case when a.bookid IS NULL
           THEN 1 END) ,
         count(distinct b.id) as lossid
     From inventary_table a 
    Left Join
    Loss_table b
    On
    a.bookid=b.book_ref_number
```

Comment: That works too. It was the right join which should have been left.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

SELECT book_name,COUNT(book_id),COUNT(book_ref_id) FROM Inventory_Table right join Loss_table on book_ref_number  = book_id GROUP BY book_name

But if you need all the books in Inventory and only matching books from Loss_table  then it should be left join:

SELECT book_name,COUNT(book_id),COUNT(book_ref_id) FROM Inventory_Table leftjoin Loss_table on book_ref_number  = book_id GROUP BY book_name

Comment: I switched it with minor changes to left join and it worked. I feel stupid. Thank you for your help.